# Why can not decode persian character from csv file with c#?

Tags: c#

I'm write this code for read csv file:

```
var reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(@"C:\test.csv"));
    List<string> listA = new List<string>();
    List<string> listB = new List<string>();
    while (!reader.EndOfStream)
    {
        var line = reader.ReadLine();
        var values = line.Split(';');

        listA.Add(values[0]);
        listB.Add(values[1]);
    }
```

and my sample csv file recode here:

```
استان نمونه عمليات دوره صورت حساب- دوره اول سال 1393    1393,01,01  1393,03,01`enter code here`
```

when i debug the my program,i get this data from up sample line:

```
��� ���� �������,��� ������
```

what happen?why can i see really data from csv file?
When i open file into the visual studio i see this:
[image]

Comment: What encoding is the input file? What encoding are you using to open it?

Comment: Also: can the font used in debugging display those characters?

Comment: @LexyStardust How can i use font ?

Comment: @LexyStardust When i use Message box to show data,show not really data again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this has to be done only once, the easiest way would be to open you CSV file and convert it to Unicode text.
Open CSV file in Visual Studio and do following:

`Choose File -> Advanced Save Options -> Choose 'Unicode (UTF-8 with signature) - Codepage 65001' -> Save the file and try again`.

According to MSDN, Stream reader should be able to pick up correct encoding.

> The StreamReader object attempts to detect the encoding by looking at
>   the first three bytes of the stream. It automatically recognizes
>   UTF-8, little-endian Unicode, and big-endian Unicode text if the file
>   starts with the appropriate byte order marks.

**EDIT:**

Change code to:

```
var reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(@"C:\test.csv"), Encoding.GetEncoding(1256));
```

Comment: I't work with your solution,but i want to auto converto to UTF-8

Comment: C# strings are always using Unicode so there is no need to convert anything. See my EDIT

Comment: what is this number:28596?

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass an `Encoding` to [`StreamReader`'s constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143456%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Without knowing what encoding the input file is, we can only guess at which encoding to use...

Answer (score 0):

This is a guess because you haven't given the encoding of your input file:

```
var reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(@"C:\test.csv"), Encoding.Unicode);
List<string> listA = new List<string>();
List<string> listB = new List<string>();
while (!reader.EndOfStream)
{
    var line = reader.ReadLine();
    var values = line.Split(';');

    listA.Add(values[0]);
    listB.Add(values[1]);
}
```

You might also want to try:

```
var reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(@"C:\test.csv"), Encoding.BigEndianUnicode);
```

It could also be a different encoding, in which case have a read here to see how you can access otehr encodings: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: `UTF-8` is the default encoding used by `StreamReader`

Comment: @DGibbs: not true - by default StreamReader will try to detect encoding from first bytes of stream (BOM). See MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143456%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @KasparsOzols ["StreamReader defaults to UTF-8 encoding unless specified otherwise"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). I guess the the `"unless specified otherwise"` part implicitly comes into play here.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that it's simply your display font which cannot display Persian glyphs, so that it shows you a default glyph (and you didn't tell us how you did the output -- message box? Console?).

But there can be several reasons why the data is not displayed correctly. You must decode the CSV file correctly, encode properly for output if desired, and choose a display method (e.g. an editor or messagebox font) which can display Persian and can deal with right-to-left scripts.

My debugging strategy (after trying to simply set an output font) would be roughly in the order of processing. It's probably a little more complicated than you expected, but I would look at the string or byte array data in the debugger after reading a trivial CSV file.

I would look at it in binary/hex format bytewise in order to be independent of possible debugger display issues. A prerequisite for that step is that you must know how you want to store the data (probably in utf-8), and what the expected byte sequence in the chosen format is. That makes sure that you decoded the CSV file properly.

Then, for whatever display method you choose (console, message box, file editor) you must make sure that it supports your encoding (utf-8, perhaps) and can display Persian glyphs right-to-left.